# namespace '/'No Scope registered for scope 'request' in JUNIT

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, struts2, junit

I am writing Unit Tests for Struts Action classes integrated with Spring.

**Struts.xml**

```
<action name = "displaySearchCertiSchedulerAction" 
       class = "certificationSchedulerAction" 
      method = "displaySearchCertiScheduler">

    <result name = "success">/jsp/admin/SearchCertiScheduler.jsp</result>
</action>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<bean name = "certificationSchedulerAction"
     class = "com.admin.action.CertificationSchedulerAction"
     scope = "request">

    <property name = "certificationSchedulerServices" 
               ref = "certificationSchedulerServices" />
</bean>
```

**JUnit**

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
public class BrokerActionTest extends StrutsSpringJUnit4TestCase {

    @Test
    public void testGetActionProxy() throws Exception {
        ActionProxy proxy   =  getActionProxy("/getEventCategoryAction");
        CertificationSchedulerAction schedulerAction = 
                                (CertificationSchedulerAction) proxy.getAction();

        assertNotNull(proxy);            
     }
}
```

**Error:**

> Tests in error: testGetActionProxy(com.admin.action.BrokerActionTest):
>   Unable to instantiate Action, certificationSchedulerAction,  defined
>   for 'getEventCategoryAction' in namespace '/' 
>   No Scope registered for scope 'request'

This works fine if I don't explicitly specify the scope, but it gives error if I specify the scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `request` scope (and its handlers) is registered by a `WebApplicationContext` implementation. If you're going to test in a  web environment, you'll need `@WebAppConfiguration`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But i have query .1) why need @WebAppConfiguration when StrutsSpringJUnit4TestCase class is creating the webapllication context.

Comment: @user3381610 It doesn't look to me like it does. It has to actually load your context configuration with a subclass of `AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext` which does register the `RequestScope` (among others). `@WebAppConfiguration` does that.

Comment: It seems that @WebAppConfiguration is part of Spring 3.2.1 but  we are using 3.1.1.

Comment: @user3381610 I've had a lot of questions recently for 3.1 that could have been solved so easily with upgrade...If you can't upgrade, you might have to spin your own test setup (with `@BeforeClass` possibly) to load the `WebApplicationContext` yourself.

Comment: i have created spring test configuration file and removed the scope for time being to make it work in 3.1.1.Thanks for the help.FYI...downgrade has not been done by me as i dont have so much priviledge being new user

Comment: @user3381610 You're welcome. (If you open an account on any other Stack Exchange website and link it to your current one, you'll get 100 rep automatically.)

Comment: Using spring boot 1.2.3.RELEASE with CXF 3.10: Obviously it is not enough to have a @WebAppConfiguration in the component scan. I still get the same error (more on my settings see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30606522/cxf-request-scoped-bean-not-working-in-unit-test-soap). What to add more?

Comment: @Heri Sorry, I barely know boot and don't know CXF at all.